# Img moves when changing opacity on :hover

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

So I have a div with an image inside it that I want to start out at 0.7 opacity and change to 1 on hover but I am encountering an apparent bug where the image either moves 1px or gets 1px smaller (I can't tell for sure which) when I change the opacity on hover.
This is apparently a known bug but none of the fixes in the other questions have worked for me.
I have tried setting backface-visibility: hidden; and doing a transform but the bug remains.

Are there any new solutions to this bug?

```
.collapse img { 
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -90px; 
    margin-left: 75px;
    opacity: 0.7; 
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
    border:none;
} 
.collapse:hover img {
    width: 100%; 
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0); 
    border:none;
}
```

Thanks,
Adam

EDIT - 
JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wfe70gd1/6/

Live example can be seen here (right column below the charts) -- http://mmdoc.ajhtestserver.com/decks/1/

Also it only appears to be happening in Firefox

Comment: I've seen this happen a few times, have you tried making sure your image is floated? Or also try specifying the image dimensions if you haven't. Some code might help us out

Comment: JSfiddle required to demo the 'bug' would be helpful.

Comment: The fiddle and website work as expected for me using firefox :/ Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 31.  This effect is subtle.  The opacity changes fine but if you watch the right side of the element shrinks and expands on hover creating a small bounce effect.

Comment: @AdamHollow The only way I managed to get rid of this bug before was to apply `backface-visibility: hidden;` to the `img` element... but you already did it. So I don't know what to do here sorry

Comment: I can see it using Firefox 33.0a2 (2014-08-31) - but it is tricky to reproduce for me as it doesn't happen consistently. It seems to happen more often if I quickly hover over both images, though.

Comment: Not sure why you have redundant properties... `width: 100%; border:none;` are applied to regular div **and** on hover. No need to add it again on hover.

Comment: Try removing transform translate. It establishes new positioning system. We know it already have issues with fixed positioning.

Comment: The redundant properties and transforms were both added as attempts to solve the bug...they both failed :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to add the backface-visibility selector to your parent class (.collapse).  You also need to include the Mozilla version of the selector.  Wouldn't hurt to include Opera, too.

```
-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: I think that worked.  I tried the backface trick before but maybe I didn't try it with the prefixes.  Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: The first line is not supposed to have a `-` before it: